# How to prevent Service from getting destroyed

Tags: android

I have a `Service` that tracks the location of user, in a time I get the location of user though of `GoogleApiClient`.

It Happen some times `Service` stop, depend of internet or model phone the `Service` stop sending location to webservice. It seems like it was destroyed.

How can I prevent this?

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
    public long UPDATE_MILLISECONDS_DEFAULT = 180000;

    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Location service create");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
        // no need to start processing a new location.
        if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
            currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
            startTracking();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startTracking() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
        }
    }

    protected void sendLocationToServer(Location location) {
            // here I call my webservice and send location
            Log.d(TAG, "Update to Server location");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Destroy service");
        stopLocationUpdates();
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       sendLocationToServer(location);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_MILLISECONDS_DEFAULT); // milliseconds for default
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


        //locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

        stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're returning `START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.

Because of this, whenever the OS kills your `Service` (to reclaim memory, for example) it will not get re-created.

Change the following line:

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

To this:

```
return START_STICKY;
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) of `START_STICKY`:

> Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`: if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will
>   guarantee to call `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` after creating the
>   new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to
>   be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
>   object, so you must take care to check for this.

*NOTE:* `START_STICKY` does not prevent your `Service` from being killed. It just tells the OS to restart it as soon as possible (depending on the available resources). To make your `Service` less likely to be killed, you can 
make it run in the foreground by calling [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to change this line of code

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
    // no need to start processing a new location.
    if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
        currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
        startTracking();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```